# Show git branch and status in Mac Bash

Tags: macos, git, bash

I use the Github for windows client.The shell with powershell is very nice!

[image]

How do I implement it on MAC?
Not only the branch name,I also want `git status`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think ohmyzsh is my best choose！

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Comment: oh-my-zsh is very intrusive for only this git benefit

Answer (score 31):

Git itself has this: https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh

Usage sample:

```
GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="auto"
GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS="yes"
source ~/.git-prompt.sh

export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h:\W" "\\\$ ";'
```

It looks like this:

[image]

The green name is the branch, the symbol before the closing parenthesis is the status.

Comment: You need to put djromero's usage sample into ~/.bash_profile. By default you probably won't have one on Mac, so you need to create the file and then use the above verbatim (assuming git-prompt.sh is saved at ~/.git-prompt.sh).

Answer (score 6):

[`vcprompt`](https://bitbucket.org/gward/vcprompt) offers similar shell prompt for Git (and Hg, Bazaar and SVN). You can install it via [`homebrew`](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/):

```
brew install vcprompt
```